# Cyanogenmod frequently restarting on xperia ZL C6506. And battery life reduced

Tags: sony, cyanogenmod, sony-xperia

Flashed a cyanogenmod rom onto my xperia ZL (C6506), and I'm having the following problems:

- Restarts for no reason
- Battery life reduced to less than a day even when idle. It used to last for 3 days on idle.
- Does not recognize/connect to cell phone network by T-mobile. It previously did. Bluetooth is ok.

  ```
  Android 4.3.1
  Kernel version 3.4.0-gd3b6d0c-00934-gc61bb0023032010@seldlx7358#1
  Build number full_c6503-userdebug 4.3.1JLS361eng.ss.20140813.032845 test-keys
  ```

Any advice? Is there a fix or a better firmware for C6506?

Comment: This question is not suitable for this site. Please shift your doubt to android.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update it from system updates .My nexus 4 also was restarting frequently after an update it fixed .If the update won't help try a newer update and if that doesn't help I don't know how to help you.